# Could I create Peltier cooling module from iron and copper?

Tags: heat, peltier, cooling

I want to create a tiny, easy to maintain one-purpose distilation unit. It's supposed to distilate expensive tetrachlorethylene to clean it from whatever is dissolved in it.

There are millions of ways to heat something up - you can burn it by candle, heat by short circuit or keep it in sunlight (at least now in summer). But till today, I have known only one way to cool something down - the one that is used in the fridges.

I was googling and thinking though, and I've learned about [Peltier effect](http://www.reuk.co.uk/What-is-a-Peltier-Cooler.htm). If effective, this would be the most awesome solution, providing both heat and cooling.

[image: peltier cooler]

In serious business though, Peltier coolers are made of semiconductors and I can't afford one. Also, their shape doesn't really suit my needs.

So I was thinking of creating many connections like the one you see above. Would it work? Would it work *well*?

Comment: Can you afford a thermocouple?

Comment: If you seriously can't afford an off-the-shelf Peltier unit, then you can't afford to make your TET distiller. End of story.

Comment: What sort of temperatures are you trying to reach?  (And how much cooling power do you need?)

Comment: I don't need much of the heating (tetrachlor ethylene evaporates slowly at room temperature), but I need a lot of cooling to bring it back to liquid state. But I can't create refrigerator mechanism...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would 'work', because iron and copper have somewhat different [Seebeck coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient) (6.5 and 19)- both positive, unfortunately.

I think it would be about useless, however. The extremely high thermal conductivity of the metals will (thermally) short the output so even the miserable efficiency of a conventional Peltier device would be unachievable.

You can buy a real Peltier module for less than $5 shipped from China, on eBay, so why bother?

Comment: Another reason to bother would be that I like to make things on my own as a proof of concept. Would similar thing work better with material with bad thermal conductivity (carbon for example)?

Comment: More heating.. I'm not sure it would be a net improvement. AFAUI, the semiconductors have anisotropic heat conductivity.. There's an expensive thermal hear transfer pad like that but it's not conductive ( by design). It would be interesting to see if you could get a measurable temperature change with the Cu and Fe.

Comment: I've heard of (but couldn't find it on the web) a physics demo where they make an iron/copper thermalcouple out of some big pieces.  Then heat one junction in a flame. (I don't know where the other one goes.) And generate currents strong enough to deflect a compass.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Using iron and Constantan (Seebeck coefficients of 19 and -35) would make a lot more sense. You can get around 54uV/K from a single junction (varies with temperature, of course). Current depends on having thick wires which means more heat flow. There's a lot of thermodynamics involved in thermocouples and not a lot of free lunches.